# Changing properties in JSON data

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

how can I change the "ABC" field in the code below?

```
 var data = {ABC:{key:'dynamic_key',value:'dynamic_value'}}
```

Normally, I can give the value I want by saying data.ABC.key, but what I really want is to go as data.CCC instead of data.ABC, so I just want to change the ABC name.

Comment: That would be `data.CCC = data.ABC; delete data.ABC;`

Comment: maybe using destructuring... but it will become a variable https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/es6/use-destructuring-assignment-to-assign-variables-from-nested-objects

Comment: mmm... Then `data.CCC = {...data.ABC}; delete data.ABC;`

Comment: There's no direct way to rename  a property. So all you can do is copy the property and remove the old one.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Destructuring is for accessing properties, not creating properties.

Comment: Read my earlier comment -- you can't. Why do you want to do it without deleting? How would you tell the difference?

Comment: @MarkAbde `delete data.ABC` doesn't delete the actual data, it deletes the key itself in the `data` object

Answer (score 2):

Re-assign the inner object to the new outer object key, then delete the previous.

```js
 var data = {ABC:{key:'dynamic_key',value:'dynamic_value'}}
 
 data.CCC = {...data.ABC}
 delete data.ABC
 
 console.log(data)
```

That also could be (without using delete)

```js
var data = {ABC:{key:'dynamic_key',value:'dynamic_value'}}

data = {CCC: data.ABC}
console.log(data)
```

---

**EDIT**... It you want to use a string from a variable to set the new key, use the bracket notation:

```js
var data = {ABC:{key:'dynamic_key',value:'dynamic_value'}}
var newKey="CAR"

data[newKey] = data.ABC
delete data.ABC
console.log(data)
```

Comment: what I really want to do is to assign the values ​​from the variable instead of ABC but it doesn't work so I was wondering if there is a way to change it var new="NEW"; data = {new:{key:'dynamic_key',value:'dynamic_value'}}

Comment: `var new` is a fail from start, as `new` is a reserved keyword. It could be `var newData`... But it is pointless to assign it a string.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but as you said, the value it takes is the name of the variable, the string expression I gave to the variable I want comes
 the result i expected: var newData="CAR"
{CAR:{key:'dynamic_key',value:'dynamic_value'}}

Comment: Okay... I think I got your question... See edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.CCC = data.ABC // on object create new key name. Assign old value to this

delete data.ABC //delete object with old key name
```

output:

```
{ 
  "CCC":
    {
       "key": "dynamic_key",
       "value": "dynamic_value"
    }
}
```